# Speeding up distance calculation between all combinations of two sets of paths

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, combinations

I have two agents, each having paths that are defined by an `x` and `y` coordinate for 100 timesteps. In other words, a single path has shape `(100,2)`. Now agent `A` and `B` both have 1000 unique paths. I want to calculate the distance between *all* combinations of paths at *every timestep*. In other words, my final output should have shape `(1000,1000,100)`. Currently I use the following approach:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(0)

N = 1000
A = np.random.rand(N,100,2)
B = np.random.rand(N,100,2)

t0 = time.time()
combinations = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N)))
combinations = combinations.T.reshape(-1,2)

# Calculate distances 
diff = A[combinations[:,0],:] - B[combinations[:,1],:]  # Differences
distances = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',diff,diff)) # A bit faster than linalg norm
distances = np.reshape(distances, (N,N,100))
print('Time:', time.time() - t0)
```

However, I have to say that this method is quite slow (about 1.2 seconds on my machine). Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: The purpose of the provided code is unclear to me. Besides this, it seems fair the code takes some times as `A` and `B` are `np.float64` arrays of size `(1_000_000, 100, 2)` which takes 1.6 GiB each. This is pretty big.

Comment: @JérômeRichard they are only (1000,100,2) each so they barely take a megabyte. The output is indeed large

Comment: Sorry, I meant `A[combinations[:,0],:]` and `B[combinations[:,1],:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the provided Numpy implementation is that it create **huge temporary buffers** that are costly to fill (mainly because they are *stored in RAM* and are allocated on the fly causing slow *page faults*). As a result, the code is totally memory-bound.

You can do that much more efficiently using **Numba** using plain loops and no temporary buffers (thanks to the *JIT compiler*). Moreover, Numba help you to easily compute that **in parallel**. Here is an implementation:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

# Calculate distances and put it in `distances`
@nb.njit('void(float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1])', parallel=True)
def computeDistance(A, B, distances):
    n = A.shape[0]
    assert A.shape == (n,100,2)
    assert A.shape == B.shape
    assert distances.shape == (n,n,100)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(100):
                distances[i,j,k] = np.sqrt((A[i,k,0] - B[j,k,0])**2 + (A[i,k,1] - B[j,k,1])**2)

np.random.seed(0)

N = 1000
A = np.random.rand(N,100,2)
B = np.random.rand(N,100,2)
distances = np.full((N,N,100), 1.0) # Pre-allocation

t0 = time.time()
computeDistance(A, B, distances)
print('Time:', time.time() - t0)
```

The loop is compiled to a very efficient parallel implementation (using *SIMD instructions*). `distances` is **pre-allocated** for better performance in iterative loops. On my 6-core machine, this code is **32 times faster** (and it is still mainly memory-bound). If you want to get better performance, you could store the distances in 32-bit floats (up to 2 times faster).

Comment: Thank you, I completely did not realise that it was related to the temporary buffers.

Comment: just to ask, what is the difference between "::1" and just ":"?

Comment: `::1` means that the array axis is stored contiguously while `:` is a regular array axis possibly with some stride. Generally the last axis is a contiguous one and knowing the last dimension is contiguous help Numba to generate a significantly faster code (eg. using SIMD instruction). If you use a function like `transpose`, then the last axis of the resulting array view is not contiguous and `::1` must not be used.