# How to make a code faster to calculate the linear distances from the point Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, process

Here is the code:

```
Outputs = []

for X2, Y2 in X:
    Color_Gradient = 0
    Lowest = 0
    for X1, Y1, grad in zip(Velocity_Momentum[:, 0], Velocity_Momentum[:, 1], Color):
        XD = X2 - X1
        YD = Y2 - Y1
        Distance = math.sqrt((XD * XD) + (YD * YD))
        if Lowest == 0 or Lowest > Distance:
            Lowest = Distance
            Color_Gradient = grad
    Outputs.append(Color_Gradient)
    print("X2 = ", X2, " Y2 = ", Y2, " Color = ", Color_Gradient)
```

Here `X.shape = (572, 2)  Velocity_Momentum = (1000000, 2)  Color = (1000000,)`.

Please let me know how to make it faster. I have tried the code above and it is very very slow. That is not good since I am trying to get the result faster.
Please let me know.

Comment: You could do the zipping only once outside the loop, as this does not seem to depend on `X`.  You could also try to split this in multiple processes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using numpy arrays. With numpy, it is faster to use vectorized operations on whole arrays at the same time, compared to loops. It also usually gives cleaner code.

As I understand it, you want to extract the color corresponding to the smallest (euclidean) distance to a specific point.

```
Outputs = []

for X2, Y2 in X:
    XD = X2 - Velocity_Momentum[:, 0]
    YD = Y2 - Velocity_Momentum[:, 1]
    Distance = (XD * XD) + (YD * YD)
    Color_Gradient = Color[Distance.argmin()]
    Outputs.append(Color_Gradient)
    print("X2 = ", X2, " Y2 = ", Y2, " Color = ", Color_Gradient)
```

Comment: Wow it is faster than what I tried. Is there any other fastest way still?

Comment: @JafferWilson You could try Numba or Cython for a faster implementation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Is there any example that can help me understand the solution? Will it be faster than the propose method in the accepted answer?

Comment: @JafferWilson It should be faster if a big loop is used to compute things in-place rather than building big temporary arrays that are slow to fill (the memory is slow and it will be even slower in the future). As for the example, there are many example on StackOverflow and the Numba documentation. Maybe you can start with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69770392#69775950) dealing with distances. By the way, it would be better to store `Velocity_Momentum` in a transposed way so access can be more SIMD-friendly (for both Numpy and Numba).

Comment: Also remember that printing to the terminal is really slow, so you could remove that print statement.